# Updating list with linq instead of for each

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach

I am a bit new to linq, I am only using linq for filtering the data.  Now, I want to write a query for the below:

```
For Each k As String In con.Numbers.Keys
      con.Numbers(k).Primary = False
Next
```

Con.Numbers is a dictionary, but now I converted it into a list, hence the above code wont work with list, could you please tell me how I can achieve it with Linq is the Con.NUmbers is a list.  Thank you.

Additional Info:
Class Structure is :

```
Public Class ContactCon
        Property ConId As String
        Property ConRowID As String
        Property Title As String
        Property Mob1 As String
        Property Mob2 As String
        Property Land1 As String
        Property Land2 As String
        Property Email1 As String
        Property Email2 As String
        Property Fax1 As String
        Property Fax2 As String
        Property Primary As Boolean
        Public Sub New()
            ConId = ""
            ConRowID = ""
            Title = "Contact1"
            Mob1 = ""
            Mob2 = ""
            Land1 = ""
            Land2 = ""
            Email1 = ""
            Email2 = ""
            Fax1 = ""
            Fax2 = ""
            Primary = False
        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you take all the values of the dictionary and put it into a list?

Comment: Yes, all items ok dictionary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't know if I have misunderstood you somewhere.

Not sure why you want to use LINQ specifically. This is perfectly clear:

```
For Each number as ContactCon In con.Numbers
    number.Primary = False
Next
```

If for some reason you want LINQ-like syntax, you could use the [`List(T).ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

```
con.Numbers.ForEach(Sub(n) n.Primary = False)
```

For course, this is not "real" LINQ, but again, I'm not sure why it would matter.

If you are really forced (?) to use LINQ, you might do:

```
con.Numbers.Select(Sub(n) n.Primary = False).ToList()
```

But of course the code is nonsense. Don't do this -- stick to what is clear and obvious, which in this case means just looping over the list.

**EDIT**

Fixed terrible misuse of `Function`

Comment: +1 I agree with you favouring the first option (minor detail: I think it should be `con.Numbers.Values`), and rejecting the third as nonsense.

Comment: @GertArnold he/she mentioned changing the dictionary to a list

Comment: Fine with me. It's minor. Main point is not to use linq as a hammer looking for a nail.

Comment: Solved.  Thanks for the help Henry, also now only I came to know that For each is a reference type rather than value type, hence modifying the loop modifies the original.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ stands for Language Integrated Query.  Query means retrieving data, so it's not so good for updating data.  You maybe able to use it to retrieve another copy of the data that is updated, but not for directly updating the original.

If you want to make a new list with the data updated, you might do something like this:

```
Dim NewList = con.Numbers.Select(Function(e) New MyObject() With {.Key = e.Key, .Primary = False}).ToArray()
```

Comment: ok, is possible to set the other way around like copying the updated values from linq into a new variable?

Comment: Without knowing more about your data structure, it's difficult to provide an example, but I did what I could.